# What do I do to stop an error "expected expression before ‘char’"?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, casting, char, format

I'm compiling my work and this error kept on appearing no matter how I edit my code:

```
expected expression before ‘char’
```

and

```
format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

as of the second error, I've tried to use typecasting but the problem is really persistent. Does anyone know how to?
This is a part of my code:

```
while ( char my_wget (char web_address[BUFLEN]) != EOF ) {
    printf ("%s", (char) web_address[BUFLEN]);
```

Comment: Get a book on C and learn the language from it. Don't just write something in the hopes it'll compile, let alone work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've got a syntax error where you wrote `char` and `char` is not allowed.

Maybe you had in mind:

```
int ch;
char web_address[BUFLEN];

while ((ch = my_wget(web_address)) != EOF)
    printf("%s\n", web_address);
```

With the correct declaration for `my_wget()` around (such as `extern int my_wget(char *buffer);`), that should compile.  You can't declare variables everywhere.

The second error is because `web_address[BUFLEN]` is a character (certainly in my code; it seems to be in yours, too, since the compiler managed to identify the type sufficiently to generate the error).  It is also one beyond the end of the array if you declared it as I did.  Treating a `char` value (probably an 8-bit quantity) as an address (pointer; probably a 32-bit or 64-bit quantity) is wrong, which is why the compiler complained.

Answer (score 1):

In the `printf()` statement, try changing the part `char` to `char*`
Same applies to the condition in the `while` loop. Change the `char` before `web_address` to `(char*)`

I find it weird that you write `"char"` before `my_wget()`. Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

See this code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char c;
printf ("%s",  st);
}
```

when i compile it , i get the same warning message.

```
 warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

so i change the program to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *str = "string";
printf ("%s",  st);
}
```

And now the program compiles properly.

So being a newcomer to c , this is how you learn the language , write the smallest example , to prove that you have a firm grip over the concept.